# Hiding answers to questions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add series of questions to students and hide the responses until the user clicks on a 
"Show Answer" button. I can get it working for the first button, but can't get it for the remaining questions and buttons.
Here is the basic structure I am using to get the first button to work. Everything I try for the others is obviously wrong! Also not sure why the CSS isn't working once I add the script. Is JavaScript the best way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV, {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ol>
  <li>Question 1
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn1">Show Answer</button>
</li>

<div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
  Answer 1
</div>

<li>Question 2
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn2">Show Answer</button>
</li>

<div id="myDIV2" style="display: none;">
  Answer 2
</div>

</ol>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var button = document.getElementById("btn1");

  if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
      button.innerHTML = 'Show Answer';
  } else {
     x.style.display = "block";
    button.innerHTML = 'Hide Answer';
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out this link: https://codepen.io/georgearnall/pen/wCskn You can find many more such projects there, and mostly the code is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>Question 1
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Show Answer</button>
    <div style="display: none;">
      Answer 1
    </div>
  </li>



  <li>Question 2
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Show Answer</button>
    <div style="display: none;">
      Answer 2
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
  .answerBlock {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
function myFunction($event) {
  console.log(event);
  var temp = event.target;
  var temp1 = event.target.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(temp);
  console.log(temp1);
if (temp1.className=="answerBlock") {
    temp1.classList.remove("answerBlock");
    temp.innerHTML = 'Show Answer';
} else {
    temp1.classList.add("answerBlock");
    temp.innerHTML = 'Hide Answer';
}
}
```

Check out the below link for the solution

https://jsfiddle.net/1kx5Lucf/

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Sorry for the delayed response. It has been crazy managing work, side hustle, isolation and home schooling! This worked a treat. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be the following. Instead of using ID's and inline styles, you can give your buttons and div's data attributes to keeps things clean. I will give the DIV and the button the same ID:

```
<ol>
  <li>Question 1
  <button data-id="1" >Show Answer</button>
</li>

<div data-id="1" >
  Answer 1
</div>

<li>Question 2
  <button data-id="2" >Show Answer</button>
</li>

<div data-id="2" >
  Answer 2
</div>
```

Then we will toggle the visiblity by adding a class that sets the display to none when added to a div:

```
div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

In our JavaScript we set up an array containing all our buttons:

```
const buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button'));
```

And also we set attach event listeners onto those buttons:

```
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', toggleAnswer));
```

When one of the buttons has been clicked, the following function will get the data-id from the button and add te class `show` to the div with the same data-id. Also, we'll update the text inside the button based on if the div contains the class `show` or not.

```
function toggleAnswer(e) {
// Get clicked button
  const myBtn = e.target; 
    // Get data-id from clicked button
  const dataId = myBtn.dataset.id;
  // Toggle visibilty matching div
  const myDiv = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-id='${dataId}']`))[0];
  // Toggle class show
  myDiv.classList.toggle('show');

  // Check if show/hide to display text
  myDiv.classList.contains('show') ? myBtn.innerText = 'Hide answer' : myBtn.innerText = 'Show answer';
}
```

Methods on the document like `querySelectorAll` return a nodeList so we'll convert them to an array by using the Array object method `Array.from()`.

Checkout the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/whxmjbfk/2/

Hope this suits your needs!